# Erro This table does not contain a unique column

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Ao visualizar as tabelas mostra-me esta mensagem:

> This table does not contain a unique column.
>       Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Não consigo fazer alterar os dados do mySQL. Não tem o Botão de editar.

Obrigado

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748073/phpmyadmin-4-0-5-grid-edit-checkbox-edit-copy-and-delete-features-are-not-a  -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922503/resolution-this-table-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox-ed

Comment: Eu das tabelas que tenho nenhuma tem dados unicos.

Comment: Ao clicar na linha da tabela que quero colocar a chave primaria ele afecta alguma coisa o resto da BD?

Answer (score 1):

> Esta tabela não contém uma coluna única.

Você precisa definir uma [chave primária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_prim%C3%A1ria) (coluna que diferencia uma linha das outras).

Quando você usa os botões da interface, o phpMyAdmin realiza as alterações através da chave primária da linha em questão. Por exemplo, quando você altera o valor de um campo, ele executa o SQL como no modelo abaixo:

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo = "valor" WHERE chave_primaria = "valor_da_chave_primaria"
```

Como a tabela não possui uma chave primária, ele não disponibiliza estes botões porque ele não tem como realizar a operação apenas naquela linha. Se ele tentar por outro campo, pode afetar outra linha que tenha o mesmo valor.

Comment: Ao criar uma coluna com ID e com chave unica e colocar de Auto incremento ele coloca nos campos ja preenchidos?

Comment: Sim, ele vai preencher todos

Comment: Ao clicar na linha da tabela que quero colocar a chave primaria ele afecta alguma coisa o resto da BD?

Comment: Não. Se você quiser, pode fazer um teste antes. Copie a tabela ou o banco inteiro, adicione a chave e veja como fica.

Comment: Numa das tabelas deu um erro: #1062 - duplicate entry '1' for key 'primary'

Comment: Provavelmente existem duas linhas que possuem o valor "1" na coluna que você tentou adicionar a chave

Comment: O Sub_ID nao tem nenhum valor repetido

Comment: A tabela possui auto increment?